# Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Authenticable, null given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Im getting the following error in Laravel when trying to use the create function in RegisterController from Laravel auth. I'm trying to insert data into 2 tables with this function, into the Users table and a table called personas that is associated with the model Persona. The error is this

> Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of
> type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\SistemaHNF\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\RegistersUsers.php
> on line 36

This is the code I have in the create function

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{

    $datos= ['nombre' => $data['name'],'apellido' => $data['surname'],'cedula' => $data['cedula'],'email' => $data['email'],
    'telefono' =>$data['telefono'],'direccion' =>$data['direccion'],'ciudadResi' =>$data['ciudadResi'],'genero' =>$data['genero'],]; 
    
    
    Persona::create([
        'nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $datos['apellido'],
        'cedula' => $datos['cedula'],
        'email' => $datos['email'],
        'telefono' =>$datos['telefono'],
        'direccion' =>$datos['direccion'],
        'ciudadResi' =>$datos['ciudadResi'],
        'fechaNacimiento' =>'1998-03-05',
        'genero' =>$datos['genero'],
        'estado'=> '1',
        'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
    ]);
    
    
    User::create([
        'name' => 'clienteUser',
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'nick' => $data['nick'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => 'cliente'
    ]);
    
}
```

Is it because I'm lacking a return in the function? And if I'm lacking it what should I return because I'm inserting data into 2 tables.
I'm new to Laravel so sorry if this is a novice mistake, also english isn't my main language, if you need myself to explain better or any other code I can gladly provide it.

The form I'm using is the form from Register.Blade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return user instance back

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    
        $datos= ['nombre' => $data['name'],'apellido' => $data['surname'],'cedula' => $data['cedula'],'email' => $data['email'],
        'telefono' =>$data['telefono'],'direccion' =>$data['direccion'],'ciudadResi' =>$data['ciudadResi'],'genero' =>$data['genero'],]; 
        
        
        Persona::create([
            'nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
            'apellido' => $datos['apellido'],
            'cedula' => $datos['cedula'],
            'email' => $datos['email'],
            'telefono' =>$datos['telefono'],
            'direccion' =>$datos['direccion'],
            'ciudadResi' =>$datos['ciudadResi'],
            'fechaNacimiento' =>'1998-03-05',
            'genero' =>$datos['genero'],
            'estado'=> '1',
            'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
        ]);
        
        
       $user=User::create([
            'name' => 'clienteUser',
            'surname' => $data['surname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'nick' => $data['nick'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'role' => 'cliente'
        ]);
    return $user;
        
}
```

As default method comment says, create method must return User model instance.

```
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: doesn't matter if I'm also inserting to the personas table using  the Persona model @John

Comment: i hope it doesn't matter since it need return user instance.let me know if you have any issues